# Loop through ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters()

Tags: apex, loop, parameters

I am trying to add some extra validation to a form by checking if the fields are not null. I would like to loop through

`ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters()`

That looks something like this:

```
{
  "type": "Cookies",
  "personalNumber": "15000",
  "j_id0:temp:applicationForm:Years_Employed": "",
  "j_id0:temp:applicationForm:Work_Title": "",
  "j_id0:temp:applicationForm:Work_Phone_Number": "",   
  "j_id0:temp:applicationForm:Value_of_Other_Assets": "",
  "com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewStateVersion": "201702211931250209",
  "AJAXREQUEST": "_viewRoot"
}
```

I was trying to do something like this

```
    List<String> tester = new List<String>();
    tester.add('Years_Employed');
    tester.add('Work_Phone_Number');
    tester.add('Value_of_Other_Assets');
    for(String s:tester){
        s = 'j_id0:temp:applicationForm:'+s;
        if(ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get(s) == null){
            //CODE
        }else{
            //CODE
        }
    }
```

And this seems to do the trick, but I am affraid that if for some reason I need to change/add/wrap a field in an apex like an output panel, then this validation will fail

```
for(XXXXX param: ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters()){

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try like this.. ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters() return a map . you have to use like below code.

```
for(String param: ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().keyset())
{
    System.debug('===key==='+param);
    System.debug('===value==='+ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get(param));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_getParameters.htm) returns a Map.

So you can do like:

```
Map<String, String> urlParamentersMap = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters();
for(String key : urlParamentersMap.keySet()){
    System.debug('key>>> '+key);
    System.debug('value>>> '+urlParamentersMap.get(key));
    //your logic
}
```